# What is the meaning of the "Temperature" mash step on Brewers Friend?

Tags: mash, recipe, software

I found the following recipe on Brewers Friend:
https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/528861/kellermeister

This is a traditional all grain recipe and I would like to brew it with my BIAB setup. 
 But I'm having trouble understanding/converting the mash steps described on the recipe, which are the following:
Amount  Description Type    Temp    Time 
--      Infusion    53 °C   20 min 
--      Infusion    65 °C   30 min 
--      Temperature 70 °C   30 min 
--      Fly Sparge  76 °C   15 min

The Infusion and Sparge steps are quite clear, 
But I don't understand what the temperature step means. 
What is this step and how does it look in a biab setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BrewTarget has the same properties for mashing, including infusion and sparge.

In BrewTarget, it means that the temperature is increased by applying external heating.

For BIAB and using a mash setup with a cooler, this is not always feasible, unless an external heat stick is used.

When using a kettle on a direct heat source, it is simpler to increase the temperature of the mash directly.

It could be that the temperature step is just a typo or misconfiguration.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @chthon, it looks like they intend for you to provide external heat to meet the 70 C temperature, not by adding more hot water but by turning on a burner or heat stick.

It is debatable whether these extra steps have much benefit versus an infusion in between, let's say 67 C, for 30+30=60 minutes instead of dividing it up at 30 & 30.  But, of course, feel free to experiment and form your own conclusions.

Cheers.